# Windows 8.1- Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise won't start

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, windows-8.1

Somehow, since monday morning I haven't been able to start MS Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise. It was working fine last friday, and now the splashscreen just blinks, and nothing else happens.

I tried:

- Fixes suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32721619/visual-studio-2015-does-not-start), [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/VisualStudio/comments/3fait0/visual_studio_2015_on_windows_10_wont_start/) and  [here](http://blog.simontimms.com/2015/02/12/visual-studio-2015-not-launching/)
- This involved check    Windows Logs (none present), removed HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0 entries in register, running with
  various options like    /SafeMode /ResetSettings /Resetuserdata and
  running the repair  utility from setup. Also the XML activity logs, which weren't present, even though I did use VS for quite some time.
- Removed all previous versions of VS, completely reinstalled VS 2015

Running it with devenv /Setup gives the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture
=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The modul
e was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
```

I think that is the problem, but I cannot find a working fix. I'm using .NET 4.6.01055 and CLR  v4.0.30319.

Please note that when I ran into the error in VS 2015, VS 2013 wouldn't start either, crashing with a TaskScheduler Exception. I'm not a 100% sure, but I can remember that VS 2013 ran fine not too long ago.

So, I'm at a loss here.

Comment: repair .net 4.6 via programs & features

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, the problem persists.

Comment: capture a xperf trace of the start of VS: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29374658/1466046 use the 8.1 SDK/WPT: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-8-1-sdk

Comment: Haha, loading PerfView relies on the same PresentationFramework, so I get the same error as with launching VS...

Comment: zip the ETL+NGENPDB folder and share it to me: https://www.dropbox.com/request/VDRyGf4sbSjBv0zjCpDZ I'll take a look at it

Comment: Done, and thank you in advance!

Comment: you used the Ui and not the script, so the required data are not included. Change the path in the script from 8.1 to 10 and run the script.

Comment: I'm sorry, but using the script I can't generate a .PDB and from what I understand, the .etl won't be of any use without it. Thank you for your time!

Comment: the PDBs are usefull for callsatcks when ngened DLLs are called. Without the PDBs you can't see the function names

Comment: run the WPRUI.exe, click on **add profile** and load this profile from my dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fyzpofkaww8f253/DotNetRuntimeOnly.wprp?dl=0 Select "First Level" and my Dotnet profile, click start, run VS and after you got the message click on save

Comment: An "event session cannot be started with any providers error". Not seeing any documentation on this error.

Comment: for me it works fine in a 8.1 VM + Win10 WPT (I selected the profile, first level and CPU usage)

Comment: Dont ask me why, but it worked after a few more tries. https://www.dropbox.com/s/vdcpu33qkauzeh1/trace.rar?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the ETL I can see that you get a [System.BadImageFormatException (0x80131018)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.badimageformatexception.aspx) while loading the PresentationFramework dll.

```
<Event MSec= "18182,2520" PID="7288" PName=  "devenv" TID="7680" EventName="Binding/FusionMessage" ClrInstanceID="39" Prepend="False" Message="ERR: Error encountered when binding to native image assembly. (hr = 0x80131018)."/>
```

So a DLL with wrong CPU architecture was tried to be loaded. VisualStudio is 32Bit, so the file at `C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.dll` is maybe 64Bit on your system.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort! It would appear that my PresentationFramework.dll is indeed 64bit. Very weird that VS ran fine not a week a go, since I doubt that an update I installed, swapped my entire .NET from 32bit to 64bit

Answer (score -1):

Restore Windows to a point before Monday and then try to launch or reinstall VS again.

Comment: Done that, still no change

Comment: Why the downvote? He said it was working fine and then stopped working with no reason. If it was something outside VS that caused the problem, restoring Windows to a point when it was working couldn't help?